# Android Progressbar Icon on Vitamio before reading video

Tags: android, video, progress-bar

I have two projects,one of vitamio player and second my project that i want to play videos with Vitamio ,the play process work fine,my issue is that i want to place an icon as progressbar in center of VideoView before reading videos and hide this icon when the video is ready to be played. specifically i placed a progressbar icon in a layout inside my own project,that icon continues to be displayed even the media is playing,how i can get referenced to that progressbar icon within vitmaio project? or (**how i can know that the media is ready to be played within my own project?**)
Thank you.

Comment: try may help http://www.quicktips.in/how-to-show-progressbar-while-loading-a-video-in-android-videoview/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your **VideoView** inside a **FrameLayout**,   add a circular **ProgressBar** with a center gravity to this layout.

get a reference at runtime on the progressbar :

```
myProgressBar = (myProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.theprogressbarid);
```

the mediaplayer send you a 'onPrepare' event if you set an **OnPreparedListener**, 
on this event, hide the **ProgressBar** :

```
myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.Gone);
```

Comment: i have two projects,one of vitamio player and second my project,how i can get a reference at runtime on the progressbar from vitamio project?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Gian i sorted out the problem i did:

```
   mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {

                mLoading=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
                mLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In vitamio 4.2.2 you can set your view in video view:

```
videoView.setMediaBufferingIndicator(yourProgressView)
```

that's it. Vitamio hide your progress view when video started